# Como alterar o titulo do botão "back" do navigation bar

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationcontroller

gostaria de trocar o titulo do botão voltar do navigation bar, alterar de "

tentei da seguinte forma mas nao obtive exito

```
        self.navigationController?.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem?.title = "Voltar"
```

Comment: Se você mudar o título do view controller anterior, o botão vai usar esse título.

Comment: Odeio a navbar padrão, o que faço sempre é criar um view por cima e customizar minha navbar, e a navbar padrão deixo oculta.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente você irá precisar criar um objeto de `UIBarButtonItem`.

Tente isso:

Swift:

```
   let backButton = UIBarButtonItem(title: "< Back", style: UIBarButtonItemStyle.Plain, target: self, action: "goBack")
   navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton
```

Objective C:

```
    UIBarButtonItem *barBtnItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithTitle:@"Back" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(pop)];
    self.navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = barBtnItem;
    [barBtnItem release];
```

Outra forma que pode tentar é que como o botão voltar pertence a ViewController anterior, você pode tentar modificá-lo antes de dar push.

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let backItem = UIBarButtonItem()
    backItem.title = "Something Else"
    navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = backItem // This will show in the next view controller being pushed
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer pela interface pelo seguinte modo.

Na storyboard clique na tela que você quiser, depois na aba do view controller.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

No lado direito nas propiedades, procure back button e pode digitar o texto desejado.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Ou você pode adicionar por comando no viewDidLoad.**

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.title = ""

Answer (score 0):

Para que fazer isso em todas as Views se você pode fazer uma única vez?

Para isso é só alterar nas configurações do projeto:

- No seu projeto, abra a pasta “Supporting files”;
- Edite o arquivo “info.plist”;
- Expanda o item “Localizations”;
- Clique no pequeno botão “+”e acrescente “Portuguese”;
- Salve o arquivo.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Depois disso é só verificar se seu dispositivo/emulador está configurado na linguagem Português.